# rJava failed to install on ubuntu server hosting shiny/rstudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server, rstudio-server

I am trying to run my shiny app on a ubuntu server hosting free version of rstudio(DigitalOcean, in case you are wondering), and for some reason I cannot install or open the rJava package. I have tried the common solutions online such as `apt-get install r-cran-rjava`and I have also did `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64` and `sudo R CMD javareconf`, but nothing seems to work. Below is my error message in R when trying to load rJava:

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
    call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
    error: unable to load shared object '/home/shushufang18/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
    libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is my java version:

```
  root@shushufang18-fiche:~# java -version
  java version "1.7.0_131"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.9) (7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)
```

Here is my R version:

```
 $platform
 [1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

 $arch
 [1] "x86_64"

 $os
 [1] "linux-gnu"

 $system
 [1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

 $status
 [1] ""

 $major
 [1] "3"

 $minor
 [1] "4.1"

 $year
 [1] "2017"

 $month
 [1] "06"

 $day
 [1] "30"

 $`svn rev`
 [1] "72865"

 $language
 [1] "R"

 $version.string
 [1] "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"

 $nickname
 [1] "Single Candle"
```

Thank you!!!